# Alternative Programs to iTunes for Music Management

Tags: iphone, software-rec, itunes, ipod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to itunes to manage ipod](https://superuser.com/questions/5991/alternative-to-itunes-to-manage-ipod)

When using an iPhone and iPod, what is a good alternative program to iTunes?

I am on windows Vista, but I am interested for Mac and Ubuntu as well.

Comment: You on a Macintosh?

Comment: Would you like to state your OS so people can have a clearer idea of how to answer your question?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/5991/alternative-to-itunes-to-manage-ipod

Comment: This is a dupe if he would like windows software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Songbird](http://getsongbird.com/) can do this with an [add-on](http://addons.songbirdnest.com/addon/12).

Edit: Looks like this only works for the iPod, but not the iPhone/iPod Touch